# comparing data with dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics, blast

So guys, I want to compare some results of an analysis of BLAST (a tool used to make local alignments with proteins or nucleotides)

The output file consists of a tabular archive with 12 columns, I pretend to compare of three columns (sseqid, sstart,send) so I make a conversion of this file to a dataframe, and I remove the duplicated sequences based on information of those three columns (sseqid, sstart,send)

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-in", "--input", help="blast outfmt 6 formata",  required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
read_file = args.input

header_outfmt6 = ['qseqid','sseqid','pident','length','mismatch','gapopen','qstart','qend','sstart','send','evalue','bitscore']
df = pd.read_csv(read_file, sep='\t',header = None,names = header_outfmt6)
df_2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sseqid','sstart','send'])

out_csv = read_file+'.filtred'
df_2.to_csv(out_csv, sep='\t')
```

My script it's almost in the form that I want, but more 2 steps are necessary:

1º In the moment of comparisons, I want to insert a variation of -10 to +10 in both sstart and send, in the case of positions match in that range, the redundancies are removed.

2º In the moment of redundancy remotion, to maintain only the line with the greatest bitscore.

Someone can help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: removing "similar" items takes much more code than removing identical items, you need to define what "similar" means and apply this to your data.  if you've got more than a few hundred rows you probably need to worry about doing this efficiently.  important details would be things like: how much data you have, how many query sequences you have, average number of matches

Comment: that said, and assuming you don't have too many matches (i.e. less than a few hundred) you might be able to get away with doing a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the query then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a function that does the removal you talked about